# How to shuffle the music in the default music player?

Tags: music

I have no clue as to how can I play my music collection in shuffle mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the bottom left corner of Music, you will see an icon that looks like two straight arrows on top of each other. If you click that icon, the arrows will cross. Your music will now be shuffled.

[image: Screenshot of shuffle icon]

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the picture with the song there is a symbol on the bottom left hand corner. If you press that a couple of times it will shuffle the songs

Answer (score 0):

Inside the player along the title of the currently playing song, there are two icon on both sides.
The button on the left is shuffle and right is repeat.

[image: How to shuffle the music in the default music player?]